# Best approach for sharing sessions between CodeIgniter and NodeJS?

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, session, cookies

I'm trying to get NodeJS and CodeIgniter to share data with each other (sessions & db data). I've googled around quite a bit for a solution to this problem, but I still haven't found the most convenient way to do things. It seems the most appropriate way is to use some sort of caching software, such as memcached or redis as wrappers are available for Node and PHP.

This is what I've thought of so far:

1. Client logs in as normal on CodeIgniter powered website. Session is created and added to memcached.
2. Client connects to a secure socket.io server using SSL.
3. Client sends raw cookie data to socket.io server.
4. Server does some string splitting with the cookie data and gets the session id.
5. Server checks the cache to see if session id exists. If yes, user is logged in!
6. User logs out on CodeIgniter site. Session data is destroyed.

However, there are a few problems that I can think of with this approach:

<strike>1. How would I cleanup expired sessions from Memcached? From what I can tell, there is no way of detecting expired sessions in CodeIgniter?</strike> - Edit - Just realized that I could set a timeout on the memcached data to solve this.

1. The CodeIgniter docs says that [session ids change every five minutes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). Wouldn't this kinda ruin my approach?

Is there a better solution out there? I'd like to hear what other options there are before I start implementing this.

Comment: When the CI site sessions timeout, will you also logout the client connected to your Node.js?

Comment: If possible, yes. I'm building a notification system so I don't want users receiving notifications when they're not even logged in anymore.